# Why CakePHP forms INSERT statement with 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' in quotes?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm getting this error, because cakephp 1.3.11 creates an INSERT statement with 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' in quotes. Similar thing worked in 1.3.9. What might I be doing wrong?

```
 SQL Error: 1292: Incorrect datetime value: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' for column 'time_posted' at row 1 [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]
```

This is the context query:

```
$sql    =   "INSERT INTO `my_table` (`time_posted`, `version`, `provider`, `date`) VALUES ('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 0, 'provider', '2011-08-03 16:11:00')"
```

I'm trying to create a new record in database from cakephp using this code:

```
class MyTable extends AppModel
{
...
function blah() {
...
$this->create()
$ret=$this->save(array('MyTable'=>array('provider'=>$provider,'date'=>$datetime)));
...
```

here's the stack:

```
DboSource::showQuery() - CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684
DboSource::execute() - CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 266
DboSource::create() - CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 752
Model::save() - CORE\cake\libs\model\model.php, line 1342
MyTable::add() - APP\models\my_table.php, line 1288
```

Comment: I think you need to show what is causing the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to be inserted, as it's not present in your `save()` call and must be getting added somewhere else.

Comment: Cakephp converts my default value NOW() in schema into 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. Now I believe it's a bug: CakePHP should assign DboSource::expression('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dunhamzzz said, there must be a place causing CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to be inserted.

Once you find it, you can use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` to save using the current time.
Or, if you want to do it using SQL, you can use `DboSource::expression('NOW()')`.

ie.

`array('MyTable'=>array('time_posted' => DboSource::expression('NOW()')))`

Comment: Thank you, 'time_posted' => DboSource::expression('NOW()') worked.

time_posted has default=NOW() in the scheme. I didn't find where, but cakephp is assigning and keeping 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' as the default value to this field . During save(), all fields are explicitly set to the default value, which causes this.

It looks like a bug in CakePHP: instead of assigning 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' they should assign DboSource::expression('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') to the default.

Also looks like it's unnecessary to assign default values in save() after create(), because MySQL will assign them anyway!

Comment: you should file a bug on http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/overview